# libconfig++8 1.3.2-2 installed but cannot be seen

Tags: c++, ubuntu, libconfig

I need a library in this case libconfig++8 1.3.2-2 and I found a .deb who install it
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/libconfig++8/1.3.2-2

But I can not see it in the package manager and when I try to install another package (.deb) which depends on it, an error appears and it claims for that version of libconfig "error dependence is not satisfiable"
Thanks in advance.